# Ubuntu Phone OS on Virtual Machine

Tags: vmware, emulation

Good afternoon. I want to try Ubuntu Phone OS. Is it possible to put the emulator on Ubuntu or Windows? Something like vmware or virtualBox. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [Ubuntu Touch Emulator](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Emulator) in Ubuntu.

1. **Installation:**

   ```
   sudo apt-get install ubuntu-emulator
   ```
2. **Instance creation:**

   ARM instance

   ```
   sudo ubuntu-emulator create UbuntuTouch
   ```

   x86 instance

   ```
   sudo ubuntu-emulator create --arch=i386 UbuntuTouch
   ```
3. **Ubuntu Touch launch:**

   ```
   ubuntu-emulator run UbuntuTouch
   ```

---

<sub>Source : [Ubuntu Wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Emulator) (see here for more informations)</sub>

Comment: sudo ubuntu-emulator create UbuntuTouch --channel=ubuntu-touch/utopic-proposed
Channel ubuntu-touch/utopic-proposed not found on server https://system-image.ubuntu.com

Comment: Oops indeed. See my edited answer.

Comment: its dont work on x64 system!

Comment: Have you created an ARM instance ?

Comment: yes i do.  i have ubuntu 14.04 x64. After start i see a black phone, and OS dont start

Comment: Make sure you have OpenGL capable desktop drivers (see [here](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Touch/Emulator)). Do not forget the first boot is pretty long.

Comment: glxinfo | grep render
direct rendering: Yes

Comment: I waiting about 15 minutes.